# Find kafka partition number programatically (or otherwise) using rust

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, rust-rdkafka

New to both rust and kafka, so bear with me.

I'm trying to seek to a particular offset when firing up a kafka consumer using [rust-rdkafka](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka). The [method to do the seeking](https://fede1024.github.io/rust-rdkafka/rdkafka/consumer/trait.Consumer.html#tymethod.seek) has a `i32` parameter for `partition` but I don't know how to find out what value to put in there... I've tried both `0` and `1` and they aren't working.

This is the code:

```rust
self.consumer
    .seek(Self::topic(), 1, Offset::Offset(1), Timeout::Never)
    .expect("Trying to seek but didn't work");
```

The error I get is:

```
KafkaError (Seek error: Local: Unknown partition)
```

This is all local using a very simple setup with Kafka inside of a docker container... so I assume there is just a single partition. I can't see anything in the docker config that would hint at a partition number and/or numerous partitions, happy to post that if someone thinks it's helpful. I'm not manually creating the topics and partitions, just letting the library/kafka take care of that automatically.

Comment: a good way to learn a lib in rust is too look at example, https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/metadata.rs

Comment: Ahhhh, I did have a shallow look at the examples but didn't see that one. Thanks.

Comment: What is particularly weird is that this function takes a partition parameter ... but clients rarely (if ever?) care about which partition they are using... they (should ?) only care about topics.

Answer (score 0):

@Stargateur lead me in the right direction via a comment above, the answer was in the [metadata example](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/metadata.rs).

Code taken from example:

```rust
let metadata = consumer
    .fetch_metadata(topic, timeout)
    .expect("Failed to fetch metadata");

for topic in metadata.topics() {
    for partition in topic.partitions() {
        println!(
            "Partition: {}  Leader: {}  Replicas: {:?}  ISR: {:?}  Err: {:?}",
            partition.id(),
            partition.leader(),
            partition.replicas(),
            partition.isr(),
            partition.error()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem for this is it will return data for **all partitions on the cluster** not just the partitions consumers are subscribed to